# netlogo turtles error with their values

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

I have two agents: buyers and sellers. buyers own buyer_Price and sellers own seller_Price. When seller price is <= buyer-Price deal takes place. I code it so:

```
ask turtles [ if seller_Price <= buyer_Price [deal]]
```

but i become this error :

```
SELLERS breed does not own variable BUYER_PRICE
error while seller 34 running BUYER_PRICE
  called by procedure INTERACTION
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'STEP'
```

its the same even I change `ask turtles` to `ask buyyers` or `ask sellers`

could anyone give some tips about my mistake, what should I change?

Comment: That code is going to be run by each turtle one at a time. Since a turtle is only either a buyer or a seller, it will only have a `seller_Price` or a `buyer_Price`, but not both. I assume each buyer is supposed to interact with some seller. Who is each supposed to interact with?

Comment: i didnt understand last question, could you please explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brian states, you will probably want to choose a potential buyer and potential seller (so the sellers don't run out of goods etc). However, if you really want all buyers to buy from all sellers with a suitable price, you want code that uses 'myself' to access the variables of the asker. Code will look something like this.

```
breed [buyers buyer]
buyers-own
[ buyer_Price ]

breed [sellers seller]
sellers-own
[seller_Price]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-sellers 5 [set seller_Price random-float 1]
  create-buyers 5 [set buyer_Price random-float 1]

  ask buyers
  [ ask sellers
    [ if seller_Price < [buyer_Price] of myself [print myself print self ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

I have just done a print statement instead of your deal procedure. You may well want to turn your deal procedure into a procedure that just deals between two nominated turtles and pass self and myself to that procedure.

Comment: one more question, i have this code in deal process :


  ask sellers [ set ownCosts ownCosts + ( seller_Price - deal_Price) ]

but i get this error comman too:

+ expected input to be a number but got the list [] instead.
error while seller 40 running +
  called by procedure DEAL
  called by procedure INTERACTION
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'GO'.

could you say please what is the problem here?

Comment: I suspect that you have missed a space on one side or the other of the '-' so netlogo is reading the backeted material as a list of two variables. If all you are doing is adding and subtracting, you don't need brackets at all. Are you using the green tick to check your syntax?

Comment: yes i do, its not syntax mistake, i dont know the reason :(

Comment: @runle: if you have a new question, please open a new question instead of just tacking it on here

Comment: i can not ask more than one question per day